# Is it advisable to autowire HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, rest

For my REST API I generate controller interfaces from OpenAPI specification files using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin. Now I need access to the request. Previously when I wrote my controllers by hand I got the request as an input parameter.

```java
@GetMapping("/example")
public exampleEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {
  // Implementation omitted
}
```

It seems to be possible to add this to the generated interface by using an extension and changing the mustache templates. Overriding the mustache template decreases maintainability, updating the openapi-generator-maven-plugin version will be more work. Besides using the request in the controller is an implementation detail, I prefer to not have it in my API contract.

Another suggestion that I've come across is autowiring the request. I prefer that solution, but I'm wondering if it is technically sound. Is it a valid solution or will I encounter problems when I do that?

Comment: DOn't. Just put it in the method. If for some reason the wrong setup is used you endup using some one elses request instead of the actual one.

Comment: Yeah, using the wrong request in one of the reasons why I'm hesitant on that approach. Previously we did override one or two mustache templates and that was a pain too, so I'm hesitant to do that again.

Comment: Injecting them should work fine, you should get a proxy. Until you don't get that proxy and then you get some weird results.